# How to commit and fetch partial changes inside a properties file in Git?

Tags: git, properties-file

For example, in the repository I have a properties file like this:

```
database.url=https://localhost...
error.message=some message
```

So properties like `database.url` are used for local development environment and should never be fetched or committed. But others like `error.message` are general application configuration which do need to be fetched and committed all the time.

So every time this file changes, I always get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    config/local.properties
```

To solve it I just save my local config in a temp file, then I perform a `git checkout -- config/local.properties`, after that I can now pull, checkout, merge, commit or whatever I need, and then I can now write again my local config.

It is extremely boring, time consuming and error prone. Is there a better way to do it? Split the file is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best way I found to solve it, is using `git stash` before checkout or merge, and `git stash pop` after that. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but I am sticking with it until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

How best to solve this depends on your build tooling, but the general principle is that local configuration values shouldn't be in your repo - and that includes the worktree unless you can use `.gitignore` to side-step them (which, since splitting the file is not an option, you can't directly do).

Typically that means that you checkout to a source structure in which the properties file is just a template with placeholders for locally-defined values

```
database.url=$DBURL
error.message=Some message
```

Of course you can't run that directly.  Your build tooling combines this template with a locally-stored properties file (which either is outside the work tree or is `.gitignore`d) to produce the real properties file (which, itself, is also either outside the git worktree, or `.gitignore`d).

Again there are many variations on this.  If you already have a considerable build process that generates lots of new files (e.g. a java project, or a front-end project that's bundled and/or minified, etc.) then it may be as simple as having a target directory for the build separate from the worktree that's checked in (as per the typical Maven project structure, for example).  Or if you want to execute the worktree in place, then the file you check in might be named `my.properties.template` and the build process might generate `my.properties`, so you `.gitignore` the `my.properties`.

Comment: Looks like an interesting solution for a maven project, unfortunately I can't do that, I am using Hybris with Ant and I have some architectural constraints to perform a change like that